# Why do Coleman functions form a sheaf?

Tags: rigid-analytic-geometry, tannakian-category

In section 4 of Ammon Besser's 2002 'Coleman Integration Using the Tannakian Formalism,' he defines abstract Coleman functions, which we can describe roughly as those functions which arise by iterated integrals along the canonical path, or more in the spirit of the paper, as matrix elements  of parallel transport in unipotent fancy local systems (overconvergent isocrystals). The datum definining an abstract Coleman function on X is if you'd like, a unipotent isocrystal V, a point $x \in X$, an element of the fiber: $v \in V_x$, and a global section of the dual: $s \in \mathop{Hom}(V, \mathcal{O}_X)$ and we think of the resulting function $f_{x,V,e,s}(y)$ as the formal evaluation of $y \mapsto s(\mathop{ParallelTransport}^V_{x \to y} (v_x))$.

Details I am leaving to the paper:

- the flavour of rigid analytic space
- the flavour of isocrystals

But there is one subtlety which I want to bring out: the unipotence of $V.$ This is what connects these expressions to iterated integrals of finite length.

Proposition 4.21 seems to prove that these Coleman functions form a sheaf, which it does by introducing at 4.16-19 the notion of a minimal abstract Coleman function (the local system is as small as possible), and the uniqueness of these. We then show that we can glue abstract Coleman functions by appealing to this uniqueness, which also glues the isocrystals.

But wait! Unipotence isn't a local property. If it were, every local system would be (locally trivial => locally unipotent, surely).

So I have a few questions:

- Do Coleman functions form a sheaf after all? Does 4.21 go through as written?
- Is there a pleasant Tannakian description of the class of Coleman functions (i.e. as functions on some unipotent fundamental group)

Apologies if the question is nonsense, feel free to tell me so.

refs (both versions have identical numbering in this section):

- Mathematische Annalen version: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002080100263
- arxiv version: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0011269